# Delphi XE5 Android Indy TIDNotify not executed

Tags: android, delphi, indy, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have reduced the code to a simple sample. 
`IdTCPClient` reads a message and should display it in a Memo.
The attached code works fine on Windows, but the `DoNotify` is not executed on android if `PostLog` is called from `ThC_Receive`. If I call PostLog via `Button.Click` from `MainForm` it is executed.
Any suggestions?
TIdSync works, but is it recommended?

```
unit HeaderFooterTemplate;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,   IdContext, IdSync,
  FMX.Layouts, FMX.Memo, IdThreadComponent, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdGlobal;

type
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TLog = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    fMsg: String;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
    //procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    class procedure PostLog(const S: String);
  end;

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  THeaderFooterForm = class(TForm)
    Header: TToolBar;
    Footer: TToolBar;
    HeaderLabel: TLabel;
    M_Log: TMemo;
    IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
    ThC_Receive: TIdThreadComponent;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ThC_ReceiveRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  HeaderFooterForm: THeaderFooterForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{ TLog }
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure TLog.DoNotify;
begin
  HeaderFooterForm.M_Log.Lines.Append(fMsg);
end;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class procedure TLog.PostLog(const S: String);
begin
  with Create do
  begin
    try
      fMsg := S;
      Notify;
    except
      Free;
      Raise;
    end;
  end;
end;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure THeaderFooterForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    IdTCPClient1.Host :='192.168.1.12';
    IdTCPClient1.Port := 1001;
    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        TLog.PostLog(trim(e.Message));
        Raise;
      end;
  end;
end;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure THeaderFooterForm.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ThC_Receive.Start;
end;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure THeaderFooterForm.ThC_ReceiveRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var
  s: string;

begin
  try
    s:= (IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn(TransmissionSeparator, IndyTextEncoding(IdTextEncodingType.encUTF16LE)));
      TLog.PostLog(trim(s));
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      TLog.PostLog(trim(e.Message));
      Raise;
    end;
  end;
end;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
end.
```

Thank you,
Spectro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When called in a worker thread, `TIdNotify` uses `TThread.Queue()` and `TIdSync` uses `TThread.Synchronize()`, both of which go through the same RTL queue, so it is unlikely that `TThread.Synchronize()` would work but `TThread.Queue()` would not.  On the other hand, when called in the main thread, `TThread` is not used (unless `TIdNotify.MainThreadUsesNotify` is set to true), `TIdNotify.DoNotify()` and `TIdSync.DoSynchronize()` are called directly instead.  If `TIdNotify` is not working in a thread, then `TThread.Queue()` has to be broken, which would be an Embarcadero issue, not an Indy issue.

That being said, `TIdNotify` does have logic to use `TThread.Synchronize()` on Delphi versions that do not have `TThread.Queue()` available.  You could try making a copy of `IdSync.pas` and modify it to undefine the `HAS_STATIC_TThread_Queue` define on Android, and then add the modified file to your project.  That only works when Runtime Packages are disabled, though.  I am not an Android developer, so I do not know how Delphi uses Packages on mobile platforms.

BTW, `IndyTextEncoding(IdTextEncodingType.encUTF16LE)` can be replaced with `IndyTextEncoding_UTF16LE`.

**Update**: a bug has been identified in FireMonkey itself (see [QC #123579](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=123579)), going all the way back to when FireMonkey was first introduced, and still exists in XE5 Update 2.  In short, `FMX.TApplication` does not assign a handler to the `System.Classes.WakeMainThread` callback (`Vcl.TApplication` does).  `TThread` calls `WakeMainThread` to notify the main thread that a `Synchronize/Queue()` request is pending.  Thus, if the main message loop is idle when `Synchronize/Queue()` is called, nothing happens until a later time if/when something else puts a new message in the main message queue.  Without that, `TApplication.Idle()` is not called, and so `CheckSynchronize()` is not called to process pending `Synchronize/Queue()` requests.  That means for background/nonvisual processes, `Synchronize/Queue()` may never work correctly at all, and sporadically in GUI processes.  Until Embarcadero fixes that bug, a workaround would be to either post a custom message to the main message queue to "wake" it up, or else manually call `CheckSynchronize()` in the main thread periodically, such as in a timer.